# Sufficient condition for function given as integral to be continuous on $[0,c]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ and suppose that $F(x)=\int_0 ^c   f(x,y)  dy$, where $c$ is some positive constant. Is it sufficient that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,c]\times [0,c]$, so that $F(x) $ is continuous on $[0,c]$?

Comment: $f$ is a function of two variables. Can you rewrite your assumption?

Comment: I have edited:  $[0,c] \times [0,c]$.

Comment: What happens when you try to prove it? (Uniform continuity)  Additional sufficient conditions may be obtained from the Lebesgue theory of integration: dominated convergence, monotone convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is sufficient. Given $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ so that
for $x_i,y  \in [0,c]$,
$$|x_2-x_1|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x_2,y )-f(x_1,y)|<\epsilon/c  \,,
$$
so for such $x_1,x_2$ we have, by https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Triangle_Inequality_for_Integrals
$$|F(x_2)-F(x_1)| \le \int_0^c |f(x_2,y )-f(x_1,y)| \, dy <\epsilon \,.$$